# Unittest is not catching exception but returns UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, dictionary, python-unittest

I'm testing that a FileNotFoundError is raised correctly by my function but it is printing the exception message and fails later as the variable is unbound. Can anyone help me understand why?

Here's the function being tested:

```
def load_users(filename, user_collection):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:

            contents = csvfile.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        print(f"ERROR: {error}")

    result = False

    if contents[0] == "USER_ID,EMAIL,NAME,LASTNAME":
        contents = contents[1:]
```

My test:

```
def test_load_users_into_csv_raise_exception(self):
    '''
    Tests that FileNotFoundError exception is raised correctly
    '''
    fake_path = 'fake/path'

    with self.assertRaises(FileNotFoundError):
        main.load_users(fake_path, self.user_collection)
```

It is failing on the if statement and not raising the exception as expected.

The output:

> python -m unittest test_main

> .....ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fake/path' E..
>
> if contents[0] == "USER_ID,EMAIL,NAME,LASTNAME": UnboundLocalError:
> local variable 'contents' referenced before assignment

Comment: What do you expect will happen? You're catching the exception, so the function will continue until it encounters the next exception or (implicit) `return` statement. In this case, the `FileNotFoundError` will cause `contents` to be unbound and you get another exception when trying to access it.

Comment: For some reason, I thought unittest would kill the execution when the exception was found. It makes sense now. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

The function catches and suppresses the exception. You could reraise the exception after printing the message to get the unit test to work.

```
def load_users(filename, user_collection):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:

            contents = csvfile.readlines()
    except FileNotFoundError as error:
        print(f"ERROR: {error}")
        raise

    result = False

    if contents[0] == "USER_ID,EMAIL,NAME,LASTNAME":
        contents = contents[1:]
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the information, I understand the issue now.